# NodeJS/JS How to correctly hash object json and string (concatenation) via sha256

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, hash, sha256

Good morning, 
I want to hash object params and string (concatenation) via sha256., but I do not know how to do it correctly. 
My object:

```
var params = {
   "name": "kacper",
   "age": 23
};
var string = "string to hash";
```

I used for it library sha256 from npm, but my encode hash is incorectly.
Attempt hash:

```
var sha256 = require('sha256');
var hashing = sha256(params+stirng);
console.log(hashing);
```

Thans for yours help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first understand what `params+string` does exactly. `params` is converted into a string, resulting in `[object Object]`. Then your final string is `[object Object]string to hash`.

Instead, you might want to get the entire `params` object as a string. This can be done with `JSON.stringify`.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(params) + string);
```

the result is then `{"name":"kacper","age":23}string to hash`.

Is this what you were looking for? It might be a better practice to make an object with `params` and `string` as fields.

```
var obj = {
  "params": {
    "name": "kacper",
    "age": 23
  },
  "string": "string to hash"
}

console.log(sha256(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it does not finish this solution is good, its not working for me, I need to hash this exactly: "Hash SHA256 with concatenation of all post values and private key",it looks like it's good: sha256(JSON.stringify(params) + string), but not working,

Comment: maybe it means to concatenate all the values in the object params? i.e. `sha256(params.name + params.age)`?